# magento 2 multi-website This site can’t be reached

Tags: magento2, multi-website, multidomain, wamp

I have setup Magento 2 in WAMP stack.

I have created two virtual hosts.

1. magento230.com
2. wateroff-test.net

   ```
   # magento230.com
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName magento230.com
      ServerAlias www.magento230.com
      DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/magento230"
      <Directory "C:/wamp/www/magento230">
          Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>

   # wateroff-test.net
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName wateroff-test.net
      ServerAlias www.wateroff-test.net
      DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/magento230"
      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "wateroff_net"
      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
      <Directory "C:/wamp/www/magento230">
          Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Now created two websites in Magento admin.

1. default website
2. wateroff website

Wateroff website configuration in admin.

1. Website name - Water Off (wateroff.net)

   Website code - wateroff_net

   Default store - Wateroff store
2. Store Information

   Store name - Water Off Store

   Store code - water_off_store

   Root Category - Water off

   Default Store View - US-English(WF)
3. Store View Information

   Name - US-English(WF)

   Code - wateroff_us

   Status - enabled

When I run url **http://magento230.com/** its working fine and **http://magento230.com/customer/account/create/** working fine.

BUT

When I run url **http://wateroff-test.net/** its not working fine and **http://wateroff-test.net/customer/account/create/** gives error like This site can’t be reached.

When i see issue in console it gives me same error for all css and js.

```
      Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I already run below command in same manner.

```
      php bin/magento cache:flush 
      php bin/magento setup:upgrade
      php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

What is the issue here I don't know.

Please help me.

Comment: did you create an entry in your hosts file? I'm not talking about the webserver vhosts

Comment: Yes I have added two entry in host file. `127.0.0.1 magento230.com` and `127.0.0.1 wateroff-test.net`

Comment: webserver restarted?

Comment: Yes restarted. @PhilippSander is there any other configuration required? I am new to Magento 2.

Comment: have you fully read an understood the magento2 setup tutorial?

Comment: Yes I follow this links [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html] and [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html]

Comment: If you remove `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` from the webserver config and restart the server, what happens if you call http://wateroff-test.net/ ? If there is no routing issue the webserver should serve the default website. Just to exclude that there is a routing / webserver issue with the domain

Comment: @HelgeB I removed `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` from the webserver and restart the server and call wateroff-test.net then its call magento230.com theme and all the links pointed to magento230.com. So what will be the issue here? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved above issue. I went through details and found that in admin I have configure wrong url.

My host file like.
`127.0.0.1 wateroff-test.net`

But in admin configuration I have added **www** before domain.

Base url `http://www.wateroff-test.net`
Base link url `http://www.wateroff-test.net`

So removed **www** and put only `http://wateroff-test.net` url and working fine.

Thank you everyone to give support.